# pentaho schema workbench no publish password option

Tags: schema, pentaho, workbench

I am currently using Schema workbench 3.6.1. I created a data cube and I am trying to publish it in pentaho bi-server. In every tutorial I've seen after clicking on publishing the pop up window looks like.

[image]

What I get instead is:

[image]

There is no publish password and I don't know what values I should enter.

How do I get the other publishing window or how do I manage to publish with this window?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Don't get confuse. Newer version things are changed.So you what you have did is correct only.

Just make sure that after publishing you are getting successfully published message or not?

Also make sure to check command prompt in which your pentaho schema workbech process runs for any error.

If everything is fine then you can go to jpivot or saiku and see the output of your cube.

Comment: I didn't manage to publish the cube. Do you know how I should populate the fields? especially for the publish settings and the 2 tick boxes

Comment: as far as I can see the screenshot everything looks proper.
username and password will be same which you will going use for loginin into bi server.

and what ever pentaho or data sorce name you will give has to be present in bi-server's data source connection list.

and uncheck register xmla data source option.